# create a timestamp for yesterday and group all of the timestamps within that range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database full of data which also has a timestamp field.  What I am trying to do is count the number of records in the field grouped by timestamp, but rounded off to in days.

I currently have a piece of code as below,

```
$days_ago7a = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") , date("d") - 7, date("Y")));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM all_count WHERE date='$days_ago7a'");
$num_rows37 = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

I want to do the same thing only replace the date with a timestamp (which is also in the database) and to group all time stamps from within a 24 hour period.

is that possible?

OK so i have changed the code to this, but it doesn't return any results?

```
$result = mysql_query("select date( timestamp ), count(*) from all_count group by date(   timestamp );") 
 or die(mysql_error());  
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) { 
  echo "$timestamp";
  }
```

Comment: first off that days_ago isn't going to work- you can't just subtract 7 from ```date("d")``` and expect a meaningful result.  What if ```date("d")``` is 2?  Try this for example (Feb 2):
```<?php
    $date = new DateTime('2013-02-02');
    echo date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") , date("d", $date->getTimestamp()) - 7, date("Y"))). "\n";```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To group by date of a timestamp:

```
select date( timestampfield ), count(*) from all_count group by date( timestampfield );
```

To get the count from yesterday:

```
select count(*) from all_count where date(timestampfield) = date_sub( curdate(), INTERVAL 1 day );
```

Comment: Thanks i added the code i used but it doesn't return any results?

Answer (score 0):

I guess easier way to use timestamp only in date (not time) range is to do something like this:

```
$date = '2012-05-20 11:25:12';
$date = strtotime($date);
$begginingOfDay = date('Y', $date).'-'.date('m', $date).'-'.date('d', $date).' 00:00:00'
$timestamp = strtotime($begginingOfDay);
```

now you have `$timestamp` containing timestamp for beggining of the day. Then you can move around with it, for example substract few days:

```
//timestamp points to 2012-05-20 00:00:00
$timestampWeekBefore = $timestamp - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60; //date - 7 days * 24 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds
```

will give you `2012-05-14 00:00:00`.
After manipulations, you can call `date` with proper format to put on your page or query.

Comment: Thanks I should have said that I am trying to get a rolling period, for example seven days ago, 14 days ago and 30 days ago.  so the base date would always change

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL date functions to the rescue!](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days)

> TO_DAYS(date)
>   Given a date date, returns a day number (the number of days since year 0).
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT TO_DAYS(950501);
>     -> 728779
> mysql> SELECT TO_DAYS('2007-10-07');
>     -> 733321
> ```

I think you can figure out the rest.